# A regex to match `.` but not in `a.m.`

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to match all dots in a string but not if it's a part of `a.m.` or `p.m.`.

`Now. Is. 5 p.m. and is getting late...`

I need it to work in JS environment.

Yes, I am splitting a string.

```js
str = `Now. Is. 5 p.m. and is getting late...`;
result = str.split(/[.]/);
```

I am getting
`["Now", " Is", " 5 p", "m", " and is getting late", "", "", ""]`

Whereas I need
`["Now", " Is", " 5 p.m. and is getting late", "", "", ""]`

Comment: So, you are splitting a string, aren't you? What is your current expression and what is the method you are using?

Comment: Added clarification

Comment: You may try a lookbehind based regex like `/\.(?<![pa]\.(?=m\b))/i`

Comment: Thank you. It produces  ` 5 p.m`, but I need  ` 5 p.m. Geting late`

Comment: It's easier to write positive matching regex than negative matching regex. It may be easier to replace a.m and p.m with placeholders, do your split, then reverse the replacement. A caution with complex regex is that it can be used against you in a breed of dos attacks

Comment: Your output is unclear anyway. You are splitting with a dot, but there is a space after `p.m.`

Comment: Sorry. Edited the string to be more clear.

Comment: @CharlesBamford, sometimes direct replacement is not possible. For example, besides this question, I also have a need to omit semicolon in timestamps; but split the string in other cases. `Look: it's almost 6:30`. I would like to get `['Look', 'it's almost 6:30']`. But I cannot do that with your replacement solution, unfortunately. Because time digits are always different. Therefore, I would need smth like `/\d:\d/` to skip false positives.  
That's why I was asking about help with AND NOT regexes.  Appreciate your advise, non the less. :)

Comment: Next time, please add `@`+username in the comment so that the user could be notified of your feedback. I noticed your question edit by chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following lookbehind based regex solution with `split`:

```
/\.(?<!\b[pa]\.(?:m\.)?)/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EwVn9z/1).

**Details**:

- `\.` - a dot char
- `(?<!\b[pa]\.(?:m\.)?)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location in string that is not immediately preceded with

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `[pa]` - either `p` or `a` (note the matching is case insensitive due to the `/i` modifier)
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?:m\.)?` - an optional sequence of `m` and a dot.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = 'Now. Is. 5 p.m. and is getting late...';
console.log(text.split(/\.(?<!\b[pa]\.(?:m\.)?)/i));
```

Comment: That looks elegant. But why is the second dot optional?

Comment: @avalanche1 The second dot is not optional. The whole `m.` pattern is optional because the check must be done for dots in both `a.`/`p.` and `m.`.

Comment: Can you explain in layman terms what is `negative lookbehind`?

Comment: I'm tryina add your name with @ but it won't let me. Erases it after I post

Comment: @avalanche1 A negative lookbehind is a zero-width assertion that fails a match if the lookbehind pattern matches the text immediately location to the left of the current position. You do not need to use `@`+name here since the author of a post you write comments to always gets notified of these comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228753/discussion-between-avalanche1-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
string.match(/(?:\b[ap]\.m\b\.?|\d+:\d+|[^.:])+|(?<=\.)(?=\.|(?<=\.\.)$)/gi)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/55oAl2/2)

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ap]                     any character of: 'a', 'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    m                        'm'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.:]                     any character except: '.' or ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: @avalanche1 What do you expect?

Comment: I never expect anything. That way I'm never disappointed and only get the pleasant surprises ;)))